# Transferring several similar named tables in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to create an interface between 2 databases on SQL Server 2008+ to copy several similar named tables into one.

I have n tables that all have the same naming convention, for example:

```
SalesInvoicePlanning2014ver1
SalesInvoicePlanning2015ver1
SalesInvoicePlanning2015ver2
```

etc.

The numbers can vary and do not have a set start (or end), but are always of the "int"-Datatype.

I also have a table "tabledir" that contains all table names as list. (one field) There are a total of 30-40 entries in that list with (for me) undesired entries. In the above example I would need 3 of the 30 tables.

The plan is to use a loop container to

```
select Top 1([name]) from [tabledir] where name like 'SalesinvoicePlanning%'
```

and then use the result as variable in the following SSIS Data transfer task:

```
Select * from [variable]
```

However, I'm stuck with the SQL statement to give me the desired tablename on each iteration.

Performance is not really an issue. Any advice? Am I wrong trying to use a loop-container?

Comment: No I don't really see any major issue with this. I would recommend setting your query as a variable and using the SQL from variable for your source.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps -

Step 1 - You can first create SQL task to get all table names into one variable lets say, TableNames of type Object(recordset) using you query.

e.g. select ([name]) as TableName from [tabledir] where name like 'SalesinvoicePlanning%'

Step 2 - Add foreach loop container to iterate over this variable TableNames to take single table name into new variable current_table and add data flow into the container to import data to destination table. Your source query will be expression like -

Select column_names from current_table